# Logic behind directories based web apps

Tags: php, web

I have been developing web apps in php which contain multiple users, or elements, and what I do is to use one file and identify the element by giving a php get, for example: website.com/user.php?id=1
But I have seen many web apps that instead of doing that, they do it through directories, for example: website.com/user/1
So I was wondering what was the logic or how is it made an app based on directories instead of gets and posts.
Thanks

Comment: It's done with URL rewriting, not directories. You can do that through a `.htaccess` file, [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is the documentation about that.

Comment: It's not. It's usually just a server-side redirect, so what you see in the browser is `website.com/user/1`, but what is actually done is that the link is `website.com/user.php?id=1`- look into .htaccess pretty urls.

Comment: It is not really a directory. You should research `.htaccess`. It looks as like `website.com/index.php?module=user&id=1` and it was rewrite to `website.com/user/1` by `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks guys, so it's not about the language or code structure?